# How to print/convert decimal floating point values in GCC?

Tags: gcc, floating-point, decimal

The GCC docs describe [limited decimal floating point support](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Decimal-Float.html#Decimal-Float) in recent GCCs.

But how do I actually use it?

For example on Fedora 18, GCC 4.7.2.

A simple C program like

```
int main()
{
    _Decimal64 x = 0.10dd;
    return 0;
}
```

compiles (when using -std=gnu99) - but how do I actually do other useful stuff - like printing _Decimal64 values or converting strings to _Decimal64 values?

The docs talk about 'a separate C library implementation' for (I assume) things like printf - which additional library do I have to use for - say - printing the result of a decimal floating point computation?

I've tried

```
printf("%Df\n", x);
```

which did not work - printf just produced: `%Df`.

Comment: http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11475 seems relevant

Answer (score 7):

As the docs say, GCC doesn't provide I/O, because `printf` etc. are provided by libc not by GCC.

IBM contributed an extension to the GNU C library, [libdfp](https://github.com/libdfp/libdfp), which adds `printf` hooks to make Decimal I/O work.

The README says:

```
When libdfp is loaded printf will recognize the following length modifiers:

        %H - for _Decimal32
        %D - for _Decimal64
        %DD - for _Decimal128

It will recognize the following conversion specifier 'spec' characters:

        e,E
        f,F
        g,G
        a,A  (as debuted in ISO/IEC TR 24732)

Therefore, any combination of DFP length modifiers and spec characters is
supported.
```

But as noted in the comments below, this library was originally only supported on s390 and powerpc hardware. It looks like support for aarch64 was added a few months ago  (September 2022), and there are directories for x86 and x86_64 so maybe it's now possible to do I/O for these types.

Comment: Ok, libdfp seems to be the way to go - unfortunately, it seems that it is not available via the Fedora repositories - compiling from source does not seem to be that straight forward, either - it complains about 'no configuration information is in libbid' - on the other hand gcc compiled code calls functions like `__bid_muldd3` (when doing operations on _Decimal64 values) - without link errors - thus, gcc seems to include libbid in its runtime.

Comment: Try the configure option `--with-backend=libdecnumber`, that allows `configure` to work for me on Fedora 17. The `configure --help` says that's the default, but apparently it's lying.  I get a later compilation failure though

Comment: It seems the library can only be built on IBM s390 and powerpc systems